# call a method in parallel in azure function with python

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

**Python version:** 3.7.3

**Resource:** Azure function

**Azure plan:** Consumption

**Goal:** Improve the speed of an azure function

Hi everyone,

I have the following code to classify mails:

**init**.py

```
### Importing libraries above  

def main(req: func.HttpRequest,
            context: func.Context) -> func.HttpResponse:
   
    try:
        req_body = req.get_json()
    except ValueError:
        pass

    if req_body:
        try:
                                        
            ### Some code in between to load the variables classes, selected models, .... Those variables are JSOn objects
                
            prediction = cfp.predict(req_body['text_original'], 
                                    req_body['text_cleaned'], 
                                    selected_models, thresholds)
                        
            return func.HttpResponse(json.dumps(prediction).encode('utf-8'),
                                status_code = 200,
                                mimetype = 'application/json')
        except Exception as e:
            return func.HttpResponse(json.dumps({'status': 'fehler', 'comment': str(e), 'stack_trace': traceback.format_exc()}),
                                    status_code = 400,
                                    mimetype = 'application/json')

    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(json.dumps({'status': 'fehler', 'comment': 'Die Eingabedaten wurden falsch angegeben', 'stack_trace': ''}),
                                status_code = 400,
                                mimetype = 'application/json')
```

cfp.py

```
def classify_mail(model_typ, scenario_name, X, vectorizer_parameters, modelFolderPath):

   ### ... some code in between 

    model = joblib.load(modelFolderPath)
    vec = TfidfVectorizer(**vectorizer_parameters)
    X_features = vec.fit_transform(X)
    result['prediction'] = model.predict(X_features)[0]

  return result

def predict(mail, mail_cleaned,
            selected_models, thresholds, vectorizer_parameters):
model_folder_path = "model"
    
    prediction={}       
    results = []

    for m in selected_models.keys():
        for s in selected_models[m]['scenarios']:
                            
            result = {}
            result['name'] = m + '_' + s

            X = [mail_cleaned]
            
            selected_vectorizer_parameters = vectorizer_parameters[s]

            result.update(classify_mail(m,s,X, selected_vectorizer_parameters, model_folder_path))
            results.append(result)
            
### some code after
return prediction
```

The method predict call 10 times the method classify_mail (This is the two for-loops). Each call lasts 20 seconds and I would like to know how to call the method classify in parallel for those 10 times and I can reduce the time of the execution of my azure function. I am getting the following error because of the timeout of the function in a consumption plan:

> BadRequest. Http request failed: the server did not respond within the
> timeout limit. Please see logic app limits at
> https://aka.ms/logic-apps-limits-and-config#http-limits.

Update 1:

I found this resource [Async method with python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/python-scale-performance-reference). However, it is not clear for me how to implement it in my specific use case.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know how to call the method classify in parallel for those 10 times and I can reduce the time of the execution of my azure function.

One of the workarounds is that you can [Set a max degree](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1207) of parallelism for the function where the execution time will be less than usual by performing the tasks in parallel.

**REFERENCES:**

1. [Bindings for Durable Functions (Azure Functions) - MSFT Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-bindings?tabs=csharp%2C2x-durable-functions)
2. [Parallelize tasks with Azure Durable Functions by Imran](https://imranarshad.com/parallelize-tasks-with-azure-durable-functions/)

Comment: Hi @SwethaKandikonda-MT tks for your help. We would not like to implement a durable function so far. Do you know if asyncio could achieve what I want?